# How do I setup MvvmCross in Xamarin Studio with Indie license on Windows?

Tags: windows, installation, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

Is there a good straight forward setup for MVVMCross in Xamarin Studio that has an Indie license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take your pick from Google:

I would recommend installing Nuget using the IDE Extensions on Xamarin Studio:

Xamarin Studio, Addin Manager, click Gallery tab, click Repostiory dropdown list and choose Manage then select the add-in from [mrward](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-addin).

Then either:

1. Install [MvvmCross - Hot Tuna Starter Pack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack/) on a blank PCL project to start working on core cross platform code from scratch (and install again on Android/iOS/Windows projects referencing the core project)
2. Use [NinjaCoder](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/618b51f0-6de8-4f85-95ce-a50c658c7767) from [Adrian Sudbury](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/adrian%20sudbury1/?ws=usercard-hover) to generate cross platform projects out the box, or
3. Follow [Stuart Lodge](https://twitter.com/slodge)'s awesome [blog](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/) with the [N+1 tutorials](http://mvvmcross.blogspot.co.uk/) with sample code that is (mostly if not all) compatible with Xamarin Studio found [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross)